# Apache Rewrite: *FULL* non-www to www permanent redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulty constructing a non-www to www permanent redirect. Here are the conditions I need to meet...

1.) Multi-domain support (multiple website domains pointed at the same directory on a server with their own dedicated copy of a database). This means using %{HTTP_HOST} and NOT a static domain name.

2.) *ALL* possible pathes (or at least standards compliant ones) need to redirect; this means directories, HTTP queries, etc.

3.) I'm using shared hosting, so I have access to the .htaccess file only.

Here is what I'm working with right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Details:

- I'm testing with the browser cache disabled just in case.
- I've removed other syntax during testing to see what replies work in their own right.

Comment: and what is not working with your snippet?

Comment: I don't know HTTP/1.1 very well, but is a 301 code valid as a response for every request? I think at the very least, the RFC says that for any requests other than GET or HEAD, the client should prompt the user to be redirected. See [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.2).

Comment: http://example.com/blog/ does not redirect, http://example.com/ does however.

Comment: @dreamlax — It is the responsibility of the browser author to make sure the client prompts the user when the server gives a 301 redirect response.

Comment: @Quentin: I know that, but what I'm saying is if he configures his server to redirect all requests (including POST, PUT, DELETE, etc) then his site might not function as expected, especially if the user declines the redirect.

Comment: Frankly, if a user goes to the wrong URI and then refuses a directive to go to the right URI instead, I'd mark that down as the user's problem and not the author's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It will also keep the URI scheme.

Comment: You’re using it with the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`, right?

Comment: Tried Opera instead, worked but ONLY for the root, not sub-directories work regardless of browser/empty cache.

Comment: My bad, was trying my blog that has it's own .htaccess file; will have to append PER sub-directory where there is a dedicated .htaccess file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This here works for me (with my domainname)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The only difference I see is the matching pattern at the RewriteRule.

Comment: This one is good, but Gumbo's makes sure that the URI scheme is kept too (so you aren't redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP).